# Вывод чисел в цикле с задержкой

Tags: javascript

Нужно в цикле сделать вывод чисел от `0` до `400`.

Отсчёт вывожу на экран, но отображаются только `0` и `400`.

`setInterval` прошу не предлагать.

Пытался сделать с задержкой:

```
// Тут переменной amount назначил элемент
for (var i = 0; i <= 400; i++) {
    settimeout(function() {
        amount.innerHtml = i + " фантик(ов) из 400";
    ), 1000);
}
```

Comment: Также посмотри вопрос [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433887/176684)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добро пожаловать в асинхронное программирование.

- Проблема в том, что все итерации цикла происходят в одно и то же время (с точностью до пары миллисекунд).
- Функция называется `setTimeout`, а не `settimeout`.
- Свойство называется `innerHTML`, а не `innerHtml`.
- В данной ситуации проще всего использовать `setInterval`, так как каждая итерация происходит достаточно быстро (меньше задержки между итерациями). Но раз уж вы почему-то не хотите его использовать...
- Идея состоит в том, чтобы следующую итерацию вызывать только после завершения предыдущей, используя функцию.

Пример:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady);

function onDomReady() {
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
    (function iterate(i) {
        amount.innerHTML = i + " фантик(ов) из 400";
        if (i < 400) {
            setTimeout(function() { iterate(i + 1); }, 10);
        }
    })(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="amount"></div>
```

Comment: @СлаваГесто да, в случае запросов к серверу вариант с `setTimeout` более чем оправдан. Если бы вы об этом упомянули в вопросе, то я бы даже заикаться о `setInterval` не стал. Ответ вас устраивает?

Comment: Устраивает, только хочется узнать, в чём прикол обрамления скобками (function ?

Comment: @СлаваГесто это вызов этой функции и передача `0` в качестве значения для `i`. Можно убрать скобки и написать в строке ниже `iterate(0);` - будет тот же результат. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/ztoukyyz/).

Comment: Топикстартер пожалуй затронул САМУЮ распространенную задачку на собеседованиях js-программиста. Вот в этом посте: http://habrahabr.ru/post/231071/ в комментариях соревнуются кто решит ее большим числом способов, любопытно посмотреть)

Answer (score 0):

Менее гибкий, менее хитрый вариант:

```js
const amount = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(amount)
for(let i = 1; i<=400; i++){
    const message = i + " фантик(ов) из 400"
    setTimeout(()=>{ amount.innerHTML = message }, i*10)
}
```