# Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?

Tags: javascript, javascript-faq

Есть `setTimeout` внутри цикла `for`:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    }, i * 1000);
}
```

Я хочу показывать числа `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, но показывает `6`, `6`, `6`, `6`, `6`. Почему?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/4340086

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Дело в том, что функция выполняется после того, что цикл закончится. Поэтому, `i` уже равно `6`, когда `console.log(i)` выполняется первый раз.

Если еще непонятно, вот похожий пример в псевдокоде:

```
У меня 1 камень.
Через минуту скажи, сколько у меня камней.
Дай мне камень сейчас.
Через 2 минуты скажи, сколько у меня камней.
Дай мне камень сейчас.
```

Получится, что сейчас мне даст 2 камня, в итоге у меня будут 3. Через минуту скажет, сколько у меня камней (т.е. 3), и через две минуты опять скажет, что у меня 3 камня.

### Как это решить?

1. **Вставить асинхронную функцию в анонимную функцию**, чтобы передать другое значение `i` функции вывода на каждой итерации. Это самое обычное решение.

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
    }, i * 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

Создавать много одинаковых функций - не очень хорошо, можно поднять эту функцию выше:

```js
function pass(i) {
  return function () {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(pass(i), i * 1000);
}
```

2. **Использовать рекурсию вместо цикла.** Это тоже обычное решение.

```js
(function f(i) {
  if (i > 5) return;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
    f(i + 1);
  }, 1000);
})(1);
```

3. **Использовать [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)**, чтобы создать новую функцию на каждой итерации. Это короче первого варианта, но IE8 и ниже не поддерживают `.bind`.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(i) {
    console.log(i);
  }.bind(null, i), i * 1000);
}
```

4. **Передавать аргументы через `setTimeout`.** Это поддерживают все современные браузеры, но если речь идёт о старых, то стоит проверить.

```js
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function (i) {
    console.log(i);
  }, i * 1000, i);
}
```

Замечу, что теперь функции в цикле ничем не отличаются друг от друга, поэтому можно сделать одну функцию:

```js
function doSmth(i) {
  console.log(i);
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(doSmth, i * 1000, i);
}
```

5. **Использовать [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)** . Это удобный вариант, но это новая возможность в ECMAScript 2015, так что еще не работает в большинстве браузеров. Если хотите использовать ECMAScript 2015 до того, что браузеры его поддерживают, рекомендую попробовать [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

   Внимание: некоторые браузеры (например, IE 11) поддерживают `let`, но не поддерживают его в цикле `for`.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, i * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Можно ещё (как вариант решения проблемы) использовать `setInterval`.

Comment: @Regent Не понял, что имеете ввиду вызов функции с `i + 1` в `setTimeout`. Могли бы объяснить? И да, в этом случае вариант `setInterval` удобен, но я хотел ответ, который работает в общем случае. Может быть, вместо `setTimeout`, там запрос AJAX или другая асинхронная функция.

Comment: Это потому что я не смог внятно объяснить. В общем, я про [такой вариант](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432541) и про то, что он позволяет менять время задержки или досрочно прерывать "цикл" в случае каких-то изменений. При этом он не так чтобы сильно сложнее/длиннее.

Comment: Так предложенные вами варианты тоже не будут ждать окончания Ajax-запроса. Поэтому вариант с `setInterval` будет работать ровно так же.

Comment: @PeterOlson, надеюсь, против правки возражений нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy спустя 2 года самое время для возражений... _"Создавать много одинаковых функций - не очень хорошо, можно поднять эту функцию выше:"_ - так ведь и в вашем варианте создаётся много одинаковых функций? Хотя код выглядит чище, да

Comment: @Regent, вложенных функция создаётся n в обоих случаях, а вот внешних - в первом случае тоже n, а в модифицированном - только одна. Пожалуй, действительно стоит на это как-то указать в ответе, только не пойму, как...

Comment: @Qwertiy понял, `2 * n` функций vs `n + 1`.В ответе можно написать как-нибудь в стиле _"Создавать 2*n (n внутренних и n внешних) функций для setTimeout - не очень хорошо, можно вынести создание внутренней функции за цикл, сократив тем самым количество функций до n+1"_

Comment: @Regent эта `i`в цикле и `i` в `function(i)` одинаковая или можно переименовать ?

Comment: @НикитаФаст это разные `i`. _"можно переименовать?"_ - я бы даже сказал "нужно", чтобы не путаться

Comment: Не могли бы вы переставить 5й вариант в начало? Кажется, уже пора :-)

Answer (score 8):

Решение на [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/)

```js
const intArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

async.eachSeries(intArray, function(i, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
        callback();
    }, i * 1000);
}, function(err) {
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {      
      console.log('An error occured. All processing has stopped');
    } else {
      console.log('Whole array processed successfully');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.4.0/async.js"></script>
```