# Как можно вызвать функцию несколько раз через определенное время?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть функция. Эту функцию надо вызвать 10 раз, каждый раз через 10 секунд. Я пробовал сделать это так, но она выводит всего один раз:

```
for (var i = 0; i <=10; i++) {
    setTimeout(funcBefore, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Нужно что было так? 10 сек пауза... итерация.. 10 сек пауза .. итерация

Comment: [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433887/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант, показывает итерацию 10 раз через каждые 10 секунд

```js
function funcBefore(){
  console.log('text');
}

count = 0;

intervalId = setInterval(function(){
 count++;
 if(count == 10){
   clearInterval(intervalId);
 }
 funcBefore();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Она же бесконечная

Comment: Обновил. Посмотри.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function funcBefore() {
  console.log("funcBefore");
}

setTimeout(
  function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
      funcBefore();
  }, 10000
);
```

Comment: @Visman, через одну же

Comment: @Grundy, точно, через 1 :) Вот думаю, вопрос я правильно отредактировал или нет.

Comment: Все равно 1 раз выводиться. Мне надо что бы выводился 10 раз. Например функция выводить слова "админ". Результат должен быть таким: админ админ админ админ админ админ...

Comment: @ttt нажмите кнопку "Выполнить код" и посмотрите на **10** выводов строки `funcBefore`

Comment: там же все сразу выводиться. Мне надо что бы все по очередью выполнился

Answer (score 0):

Через 10 секунд запускается цикл из 10 итераций с вызовом функции

```
function funcBefore (i) {
    console.log(i);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        funcBefore(i);
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос (до редактирования).

Comment: Все равно 1 раз выводиться. Мне надо что бы выводился 10 раз. Например функция выводить слова "админ". Результат должен быть таким: админ админ админ админ админ админ...

Comment: Каждый раз 10 секунд!