# Почему функция в цикле не срабатывает?

Tags: javascript, jquery, циклы, функции

В массиве значения радиусов закругления уголков. В цикле первая цепочка методов предназначена для того, чтобы в элемент с соответствующим тегом вписать нужный текст. С этой задачей код справляется. Но вторая цепочка методов в пределах цикла не работает, то есть нажимая на кнопки уголки блока не станут круглыми. Почему? И как сделать так, чтобы за каждым из указанным элементов закреплялся свой обработчик?

```
    var arr = [10,30,50,70,90];

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        $("#btn" + (i + 1)).text((arr[i]) + " px");
        $("#btn" + (i + 1)).on("click", function() {
            $(".block").css("border-radius", arr[i]);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Из [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433887) вам, скорее всего, подойдет вариант `5. Использовать let`. Вот вам [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/pabx0zr4/)

Comment: Да, сработало. Благодарю. Займусь тем, чтобы осмыслить.

Comment: заодно почитайте про hoisting.