# Обратится к элементу по индексу JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, frontend

Ребят допустим у меня есть 10 блоков с классом block а так же 10 c классом block2,  как сделать что б при нажатии на блоки с классом block над  block2 происходило какое то событие к примеру добавлялся текст или изменялись стили не важно, я хочу знать как обращаться к элементам по индексу , к примеру нажимаю на block с индексом 1 , и у block2 с тем же индексом что то происходило, я уверен что многие из вас используют это на практике, так что прошу мне помочь

Comment: добавьте ваши попытки в вопрос, добавьте ваш [mcve]

Comment: $('document').ready(function(){
        var $set = $('.div');
        $('.div').on('click', function () {
          var n=$set.index(this);   
          var $header = $('header');
          var $header__in=$header.index[n];
          $header__in.hide();
        });
      });
Вот к примеру. я получил индекс .div но как связать их с индексом header

Comment: $('document').ready(function(){
        var $set = $('.div');
        $('.div').on('click', function () {
          var n=$set.index(this);   
          var $header = $('header');
          var $header__in=$header.index[n];
          $header__in.hide();
        });
      });

Вот что я пытался сделать , мне удалось получить индекс элемента с классом div на который был совершен клик , теперь я хочу что б изменения произошли с элементом header у которого точно такой же индекс только в массиве header

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433887/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7)

Comment: дополните кодом вопрос

Comment: Ребят ответ уже дан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примитивный пример. Думаю, объясняет принцип.

```js
var clickable = $('.block1');
  var changed = $('.block2');
  clickable.on('click', function(){
    var n = clickable.index(this);
    changed.eq(n).html('Added');
    changed.eq(n).toggleClass('add');
});
```

```css
.wrapp {
border: 2px dotted black;
width: 40%;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
}
.block1, .block2{
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border: 2px solid black;
text-align: center;
font-size: 24px;
}
.block1:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}
.add {
background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="block1">1</div>
  <div class="block1">2</div>
  <div class="block1">3</div>
  <div class="block1">4</div>
  <div class="block1">5</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapp">
  <div class="block2">1</div>
  <div class="block2">2</div>
  <div class="block2">3</div>
  <div class="block2">4</div>
  <div class="block2">5</div>
</div>
```