# В IE 11 не работает JS обработчик события

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, события, handlers

Есть код:

```
var menuItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');
var subMenu = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu');

for (let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {
  menuItem[i].classList.add('off-arrow');

  menuItem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    subMenu[i].style.display = 'block';
    this.classList.add('on-arrow');
    this.classList.remove('off-arrow');
  });

  menuItem[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    subMenu[i].style.display = 'none';
    this.classList.remove('on-arrow');
    this.classList.add('off-arrow');
  });
}
```

Вкратце говоря этот код просто поворачивает треугольную стрелку при наведении мыши и убирает при отведении. Не могу понять почему не работает в IE 11. При наведение в IE в консоль выводится ошибка "SCRIPT5007: Не удалось получить свойство "style" ссылки, значение которой не определено или является NULL"

[Ссылка](https://artifactgameplay.ru/) на сам ресурс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему путем присвоения в новую переменную итерацию цикла.

let hasItem = menuItem[i];

let toggleMenu = subMenu[i];

```
for (let i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++) {

  let hasItem = menuItem[i];
  let toggleMenu = subMenu[i];

  hasItem.classList.add('off-arrow');

  hasItem.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    toggleMenu.style.display = 'block';
    this.classList.add('on-arrow');
    this.classList.remove('off-arrow');
  });

  hasItem.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    toggleMenu.style.display = 'none';
    this.classList.remove('on-arrow');
    this.classList.add('off-arrow');
  });
}
```

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что вы вовсе не решили проблему... Проверьте еще раз, желательно на меню с несколькими элементами.

Comment: Могу перелазить на хостинг с кодом который написал в ответе. Убедитесь что все работает как положено.

Comment: Ну-ну, перезаливайте.

Comment: Только чтобы там два элемента с классом `.menu-item-has-children` было. Один-то конечно же будет работать - но для него цикл не нужен.

Comment: Да согласен появилась новая проблема. С несколькими выпадающими меню.

Comment: Вообщем эту проблему тоже решил вместо обычной перемены задал let. Сейчас пере залью.

Comment: Вот теперь другое дело.

Answer (score 4):

В IE 11 let некорректно работает внутри цикла, привязывая переменную к общему LexicalEnvironment цикла вместо LexicalEnvironment внутреннего блока. Фактически, он работает как var.

Попробуйте другое решение из этого ответа: [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433888/178779)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию про IE11 let. В IE пусть работает как var в других желательно чтоб работал как он работает.