# Как задать onmouseover нескольким элементам?

Tags: javascript

Как видите у меня тут 8 блоков `project-box` класса к которым нужно применить **onmouseover** эффект.Я очень долго сломал голову но все же не понял как сделать чтобы при наведение на любого из блоков

> задний фон родителского элемента **(intro)** менялось

при том что у каждого блока должна быть своя картинка то есть если навести на первый блок должен показан ссылка которая в переменной  **bg1** если на второй то **bg2** и так далее.*Варианты через `CSS` также `jQuery` не нужны* легкие решение пожалуйста не предлагать.Также у меня был вариант решить данныю проблему таким образом на каждый блок давать id и каждому вешать такую функцию типо

```
let imgHolder = "assets/blue.jpg"; // ссылка на картинку
let projectBox = document.getElementById("#project-box-1");//берем все блоки куда будем Ховерить  через İD
projectBox.onmouseover = () => {
    intro.style.backgroundImage = imgHolder;
}
```

Но так нельзя повторять 8 раз такую функцию  нужен более гибкий вариант.

Вот мой код.

```js
let bg1 = "url('https://cdn.allwallpaper.in/wallpapers/1920x1080/2939/architecture-interior-design-kitchen-living-room-1920x1080-wallpaper.jpg')";

let bg2 = "url('https://www.hillhouseinteriors.com/images/hillhouse-interiors-design/hillhouse-interiors-design-4.jpg')";

let bg3 = "url('http://www.catalysticmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/modern-tv-rooms-design-with-ideas-hd-images-home-mariapngt.jpg')";

let bg4 = "url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/36/c4/e6/36c4e61a3993e5b4f16e810cc5ce7935.jpg')";

let bg5 = "url('http://www.3dpower.in/images/Interior%20Design/full/3d-designing-services-bedroom-interior-design.jpg')";

let intro = document.querySelector(".intro");
let projectBox = document.querySelectorAll(".project-box");


for (let i = 0; i < projectBox.length; i++) {
    projectBox[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        intro.style.backgroundImage = bg1;
    });
}
```

```css
.intro {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    padding-top: 11.3rem;
    padding-bottom: 7rem;
    background-image: url("http://paul-themes.com/html/inter/images/bg/bg2-4.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.col-project-box {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.project-box {
    padding-bottom:75%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.project-box:hover {
    background: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
.project-box-inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2.14rem 1.928rem;
}
.project-box h5 {
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.project-category {
    color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row parent-intro">
        <div class="intro">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2 class="title-uppercase" style="color:#fff;">latest projects</h2>
                        <div class="row-project-box row">
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                                    <div class="project-box-inner">
                                        <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                                        <div class="project-category"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: К изучению: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433887/178779

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function projectBoxMouseOver() {
  intro.style.backgroundImage = this.dataset.background;
}

let intro = document.querySelector(".intro");
let projectBox = document.querySelectorAll(".project-box");

for (let i = 0; i < projectBox.length; i++) {
  projectBox[i].addEventListener('mouseover', projectBoxMouseOver);
}
```

```css
.intro {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding-top: 11.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
  background-image: url("http://paul-themes.com/html/inter/images/bg/bg2-4.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.col-project-box {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.project-box {
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.project-box:hover {
  background: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
}

.project-box-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2.14rem 1.928rem;
}

.project-box h5 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.project-category {
  color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row parent-intro">
    <div class="intro">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="title-uppercase" style="color:#fff;">latest projects</h2>
            <div class="row-project-box row">
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box" data-background="url('https://cdn.allwallpaper.in/wallpapers/1920x1080/2939/architecture-interior-design-kitchen-living-room-1920x1080-wallpaper.jpg')">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box" data-background="url('https://www.hillhouseinteriors.com/images/hillhouse-interiors-design/hillhouse-interiors-design-4.jpg')">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box" data-background="url('http://www.catalysticmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/modern-tv-rooms-design-with-ideas-hd-images-home-mariapngt.jpg')">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box" data-background="url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/36/c4/e6/36c4e61a3993e5b4f16e810cc5ce7935.jpg')">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box" data-background="url('http://www.3dpower.in/images/Interior%20Design/full/3d-designing-services-bedroom-interior-design.jpg')">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box" data-background="">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-project-box  col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
                <a href="#" class="project-box">
                  <div class="project-box-inner">
                    <h5>UCAM Minimalist Apartment</h5>
                    <div class="project-category"></div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ я незнал про такую штуку как dataset :(

Comment: @Spectr можно было использовать любой custom атрибут, но `dataset` - часть спецификации