# xhr onreadystatechange для каждого элемента массива. Проблемы с асинхронностью

Tags: javascript, xhr

```
for(var i = 0; i < confs.length; i++ ) {

   var configData = conf[i].data

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', url, true);
   xhr.send();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState != 4) return;
       if (this.status != 200) {
           return;
       }

       myMethod(configData);
   };
}
```

Почему myMethod вызывается не для каждого элемента массива, а только для последнего но несколько раз. Как этого избежать? Как сделать onreadystatechange для каждого элемента?

Comment: Причина происходящего аналогична тому, что здесь: [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433887) (возможно, дубликат, но не уверен)

Answer (score 0):

`var configData` - это одна и та же переменная для всех итераций цикла. Ее декларация переносится компилятором в начало функции - наружу из цикла. После завершения цикла - задолго до того, как начнут вызываться обработчики `onreadystatechange` - в нее будет записано последнее значение, и там оно и будет оставаться.

```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('GET', url, true);
   xhr.configData = confs[i].data;
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState != 4) return;
       if (this.status != 200) {
           return;
       }
       myMethod(this.configData);
   };
   xhr.send();
```

или

```
for(var i = 0; i < confs.length; i++ ) {
   let configData = confs[i].data;
```