# KЧто выведет следующий код на JavaScript и почему

Tags: javascript

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: чет у вас какая-то ерунда написана с ошибками

Comment: нормально отформатируйте пример. и явные опечатки исправьте

Comment: Выведет ошибку интерпретатора, потому что в коде допущена ошибка.

Comment: извините, вот переделанный код

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433887/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}
```

### немного отсебятины:

человеку с инженерным образованием может быть проще понять так:

1. setTimeout - выполняется с задержкой (в данном случае в 100 мс)
2. в цикле

   - объявление `var` выделяет одну "ячейку" в памяти и на эту одну и туже "ячейку" всегда ссылается переменная `i`
   - объявление `let` при каждой итерации выделяет новую "ячейку", таким образом переменная `i` на каждом шаге перебора цикла ссылается на новый адрес.

---

Я считаю нецелесообразным лезть в высокие материи и пытаться связать `let` и `scope`, а предлагаю просто запомнить, как один из частных случаев использования циклов (`for/for-in/for-of -- var/let`).

---

**Qwerty_Wasd**:

> Возможный дубликат вопроса: [*Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433887/232932)

хотя [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433888/232932), данный **Peter Olson**, хорош и рассматривает различные способы решения проблемы - его возраст насчитывает три года. думаю на сегодняшний день **es2015**(не путать с **es5**) не только можно, но и нужно считать нижней планкой для изучения js, поэтому акцентирую внимает на использовании `let`.

## let © https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const#let

### 3. При использовании в цикле, для каждой итерации создаётся своя переменная.

Переменная `var` – одна на все итерации цикла и видна даже после цикла:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { /* … */ }

alert(i); // 10
```

С переменной `let` – всё по-другому.

Каждому повторению цикла соответствует своя независимая переменная let. Если внутри цикла есть вложенные объявления функций, то в замыкании каждой будет та переменная, которая была при соответствующей итерации.

Это позволяет легко решить классическую проблему с замыканиями, описанную в задаче Армия функций.

```js
function makeArmy() {

  let shooters = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    shooters.push(function() {
      alert(i); // выводит свой номер
    });
  }

  return shooters;
}

var army = makeArmy();

army[0](); // 0
army[5](); // 5
```

Если бы объявление было `var i`, то была бы одна переменная `i` на всю функцию, и вызовы в последних строках выводили бы `10` (подробнее – см. задачу [Армия функций](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/make-army)).

А выше объявление `let i` создаёт для каждого повторения блока в цикле свою переменную, которую функция и получает из замыкания в последних строках.