# выполнение socket.io в цикле

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при использовании socket.io: 
есть цикл в нем находится socket.emit('event', callback)
у меня не получается дождаться ответа от on и обрабатывается только последнее значение цикла. Как мне дождаться ответа socket.emit и дождаться выполнения и после выполнения продолжать перебор цикла. пробовал async / await, не помогает

Серверная часть:

```
socket.on ('GetProducts',  (params, callback) => {
    idCat =  params['idCat'];
    var url = 'страница json'
     http.get (url, res => {
      res.setEncoding ('utf8');
      var body = '';
       res.on ('data', data => {
        body += data;
      });
      res.on ('end',  () => {
        json =  JSON.parse (body);
        callback (json);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Клиентская часть:

```
function ControlChecked () {
  $ ('#tableListProductLeads').empty ();
  socket = [];
  $ ('#tableCategoreLeads > tr > th > input').each ( (index, element) => {
    if ($ (element).is (':Checked')) {
      socket[index] =  io (ArdServ);
      idCat =  $ (element).attr ('idCat');
       socket[index].emit ('GetProductsLeads', {idCat},  data => {
        data =  data['data'];
          FilltableListProductLeads (data, idCat);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам тогда цикл? Получите нужное, сохраните индекс этого "нужного" и вызывайте тогда, когда необходимо.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что Вы хотите добиться таким перебором. Вы хотите на сервер послать событие столько раз, сколько инпутов имеют атрибут Checked?

Comment: инпуты загружаются динамичепски  с json, собственно и этот запрос у меня должен принимать json. сейчас инпутов порядка 20 штук

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы в цикле плодите новые сокеты? Может достаточно одного и создать событие на клиенте для прослушивания ответа?

Переделайте так:

Серверная часть:

```
socket.on ('GetProducts',  (params, callback) => {
    idCat =  params['idCat'];
    var url = 'страница json'
     http.get (url, res => {
      res.setEncoding ('utf8');
      var body = '';
       res.on ('data', data => {
        body += data;
      });
      res.on ('end',  () => {
        json =  JSON.parse (body);
        callback (json);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Клиентская часть:

```
function ControlChecked () {
  $ ('#tableListProductLeads').empty ();
  socket = [];
  $ ('#tableCategoreLeads > tr > th > input').each ( (index, element) => {
    if ($ (element).is (':Checked')) {
      socket[index] =  io (ArdServ);
      idCat =  $ (element).attr ('idCat');
      GetProductsLeads(socket[index], idCat);
    }
  });
}

function GetProductsLeads(socket, id) {
    socket.emit ('GetProductsLeads', {id},  data => {
       data =  data['data'];
       FilltableListProductLeads (data, id);
    });
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, но результат тот же. Проблема я так понимаю в том что emit вызывается сразу же в цикле и не успевает обработаться после чего идёт следующая отправка, поэтому и выводится последнее значение on. А вот как дождаться окончания обработки emit и принять on, обработал его и потом дальше идти по циклу?

Comment: Так у вас когда приходит ответ в коллбэк эмита, то переменная idCat принимает последнее значение цикла, оно одно для всех коллбэков.

Comment: Ответ обновил. Похоже ваша ситуация https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433887/