# WebSQL. Insert в цикле FOR или WHILE

Tags: javascript, while, for, websqldatabase

Не могу разобраться, как заставить исполняться транзакцию каждый раз в цикле, а не только последний. 
Код специально упростил. Получается что uid генерится новый и попадает в Insert, a i всегда принимает значение последнего.

```js
var db = openDatabase("testdb", "1.0", "Web SQL Storage", 1 * 1024 * 1024);
db.transaction(
  function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + "idx INTEGER)", [], null, null);
  });
var a = 10;
var i = 0;
while (i < a) {
  function uid() {
    return 'xxxxxxxxxxxx4xxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
        v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
      return v.toString(16);
    });
  };
  db.transaction(
    function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test(id, idx) VALUES (?, ?)", [uid(), i], null, null);
      console.log(i);
    }
  );
  i++;
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Как исправить, учитывая что все делаю только гугля, так как JS не знаю.. Просто надо...

UPD: Проблема с i была вызвана замыканием. Решается еще одним замыканием. Создаем ее копию в локальной области видимости на каждом шаге цикла.
Но задачу усложняем. Нам нужно пробежаться, допустим по всем элементам страницы и внести значения всех ссылок в бд.

```js
var db = openDatabase("testdb", "1.0", "Web SQL Storage", 1*1024*1024);
db.transaction(
 function(tx) {
  tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, idx INTEGER, url TEXT)", [], null, null);
});
var i = 0;
var list = $('a[class*=js-gps-track]');
while (i < list.length){
 a = list[i].href
 function uid() {
  return 'xxxxxxxxxxxx4xxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
   var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
   return v.toString(16);
  });
 };
 (function(i){
  db.transaction(
   function(tx){
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test1(id, idx, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [uid(), i, a], null, null);
    console.log(i);
   }
  ); 
 })(i);
  i++;
}
```

Теперь у нас и i и uid уникальные для каждой записи. Но ссылка всегда одна... К сожалению, именно эту задачу мне и предстоит решить, поэтому и обращаюсь за помощью.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы что серьёзно хотите через js запросы в базу отправлять? Катастрофа...

Comment: @And это же браузерная БД. В чем катастрофа?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433887/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7)

Comment: Только сейчас понял, что если загнать uid()  в переменную, то значение каждый раз будет одно. (а в последнем примере, строка будет одна, так как на id навешана уникальность.)

Comment: Это-же браузер, совершенно верно, я же зайдя к вам на страницу могу изменить код как хочу. А теперь представьте, что будет с вашей базой.

Comment: @And, у меня задача пробежаться по странице и собрать данные для анализа.. Не более того...

Answer (score 0):

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test1(id, idx, url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [uid(), i, list[i].href], null, null);
```

Если так, то все работает верно...
Чтобы в итоге все заработало, нужно объявлять a, через let:

```
let a = list[i].href
```