# несколько вариантов в indexOf

Tags: javascript, indexof

Я не силен в js и только начинаю разбираться с ним. Смог смастерить вот такой код, его задача:

найти в тексте который вводят в input слово и если оно есть, подгрузить html из файла в elementID на страницу.

Таких запросов около 10, каждый выводит разные файлы

```js
var text = "разный всякий текст где есть слово которое надо определить"
if (text.toUpperCase().indexOf("слово".toUpperCase()) != -1) {
  fetch('pageurl.html')
    .then(data => data.text())
    .then(html => document.getElementById('elementID').innerHTML = html);
}
```

```html
<div id='elementID'> </div>
```

Все работает, но никак не получается в `indexOf()` указать несколько вариантов которые нужно проверить. Что-то типа `.indexOf("слово" или "слово" или "слово".toUpperCase())`

Comment: `includes` пробовали?

Comment: нет, не пробовал, а как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как это сделать

можно так:

сработает, если все слова будут найдены

если есть необходимость делать какое-то действие на 1 совпадение, то `counter` можно убрать, после `if` сразу делать `return true;`, а после цикла `return: false;`

```js
function checker(text, words) {
  let counter = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (text.includes(words[i]))
      counter++;
  }

  return counter === words.length ? true : false;
}

function init() {
  const text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus!';
  const words = ['amet', 'minus!'];

  if (checker(text, words))
    console.log('do something...');
}

init();
```

**UPD.** если любое совпадение

```js
function checker(text, words) {
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (text.includes(words[i]))
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}

function init() {
  const text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, minus!';
  const words = ['foo', 'baz', 'dolor'];

  if (checker(text, words))
    console.log('do something...');
}

init();
```

Comment: А как быть с регистром?
Можно пример кода без counter, нужно найти любое совпадение

Comment: Вопрос с регистром решил, а вот с отключением counter не могу, действие происходит только если все слова найдены

Comment: @ПавелКац, обновил

Comment: Шикарно работает. Спасибо!

Comment: @ПавелКац, желаю успехов!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let text = 'разный всякий текст где есть слово которое надо определить'; 
const words = new Set(text.split(/\s+/).map(w => w.toLowerCase())); 
const result = ['текст', 'есть', 'сепульки'].map(
  word => ({ [word]: words.has(word) }) 
); 
const allWordsIncluded = result.every(rslt => Object.values(rslt)[0]); 
console.log(result); 
console.log('все ли слова есть в тексте: ' + allWordsIncluded);
```

---

В общем виде, можно все реализовать примерно так:

```
const foo = (text, outputElem, rules) => { 
  const words = new Set(text.split(/\s+/).map(w => w.toLowerCase())); 
  const fetches = rules
    .filter(rule => words.has(rule.word))
    .map(rule => fetch(rule.file).then(response => response.text()); 
  Promises.all(fetches).then(html => outputElem.innerHTML = html.join('\n')); 
}; 

const rules = [
  { word: 'текст', file: 'one.html' }, 
  { word: 'есть', file: 'two.html' }, 
  { word: 'слово', file: 'three.html' }, 
]; 
const input = document.querySelector('#input'), 
      output = document.querySelector('#output'); 
input.addEventListener('change', e => foo(e.target.value, output, rules));
```

, но сомневаюсь что разметка полных документов (с доктайпом, `<head>`, и т.д.) будет корректно отображаться в элементе...

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = new Set(["слово", "другое", "ещё", "и", "ёж"])

// ...

for (var x of text.toLowerCase().split(/[^a-zа-яё]/i)) {
  if (words.has(x)) {
    // ...
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: заменил слова на свои и добавил действие, вообще ничего не происходит

Comment: Скорее всего тебе сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/433888/178988