# Помогите решить задачу плиз

Tags: javascript, контекст

1. Найти ошибки в коде

   > Разработчик Василий торопился на встречу с коллегами, поэтому быстро написал программу. Код получился неидеальным. Помогите Василию исправить ошибки в коде:

```
const participants = ["Mary", "Kate"]

const sports = ["football", "hockey"]

function func(participants, sports) {
  /**  
   * Подобно оператору new создает экземпляр объекта,  
   * используя функцию-конструктор и параметры для нее  
   */
  function constructFrom(fnConstructor, params) {
    const res = {};

    fnConstructor.bind(res).call(params);

    Object.setPrototypeOf(res, fnConstructor);
    return res;
  }

  /**  
   * Создает пары вида [’вид спорта’, ’имя участника’],  
   * где первому виду спорта соответствует последний участник  
   */
  
  function assignParicipants() {
    const participants = this.participants;
    const sports = this.sports;
    const orderIndexes = [];
    let i = sports.length;

    while (i--) {
      orderIndexes.push(function () {
        return i;
      });
    }

    return orderIndexes.map(
      (getSportIndex, i) => [sports[i], participants[getSportIndex()]]
    );
  }

  function Contest(participants, sports) {
    this.participants = participants;
    this.sports = sports;
  }

  Contest.prototype.assignParicipants = assignParicipants;

  const contest = constructFrom(Contest, participants, sports);

  return contest.assignParicipants();
}
console.log(func(participants, sports));
```

2. И отправить исправленный вариант в качестве решения.

```
[["football","Kate"],["hockey","Mary"]]
```

Comment: и как ваши успехи?

Comment: Запутался в цепочке контекстов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первая строчка, которая бросается в глаза

```
fnConstructor.bind(res).call(params);
```

Что в ней происходит

1. устанавливается контекст в `res`
2. полученная функция вызывается с переданным контекстом `params`, который игнорируется, так как у результата функции `bind` нельзя сменить контекст.

Очевидно, здесь идет попытка вызвать функцию с переданными параметрами, передав ей в качестве контекста новый объект.

Для этого можно использовать метод [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
fnConstructor.apply(res, params);
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что подразумевается возможность передать несколько параметров, поэтому `params` должен быть коллекцией, содержащей все переданные параметры.

Чтобы добиться этого нужно использовать синтаксис для [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) в определении функции

```
function constructFrom(fnConstructor, ...params) {
```

В этом случае первый параметр будет помещен в fnConstructor, а все оставшиеся собраны в params.

Далее идет установка прототипа для нового объекта. Стоит обратить внимание, что в качестве прототипа должен устанавливаться прототип функции конструктора, а не сам конструктор

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(res, fnConstructor.prototype);
```

---

Следующий недочет связан с замыканием переменной в цикле. Подробнее о решении этой проблемы можно посмотреть в ответе на вопрос [Почему асинхронная функция внутри цикла выполняет последнюю итерацию много раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433887/186999)

Например, можно сохранять значение счетчика на каждой итерации в переменную объявленную с помощью `let`.

---

Исправив указанные недочеты получаем ожидаемый ответ:

```js
const participants = ["Mary", "Kate"]

const sports = ["football", "hockey"]

function func(participants, sports) {
  /**  
   * Подобно оператору new создает экземпляр объекта,  
   * используя функцию-конструктор и параметры для нее  
   */
  function constructFrom(fnConstructor, ...params) {
    const res = {};

    fnConstructor.apply(res, params);

    Object.setPrototypeOf(res, fnConstructor.prototype);
    return res;
  }

  /**  
   * Создает пары вида [’вид спорта’, ’имя участника’],  
   * где первому виду спорта соответствует последний участник  
   */

  function assignParicipants() {
    const participants = this.participants;
    const sports = this.sports;
    const orderIndexes = [];
    let i = sports.length;

    while (i--) {
      let ii = i;
      orderIndexes.push(function() {
        return ii;
      });
    }

    return orderIndexes.map(
      (getSportIndex, i) => [sports[i], participants[getSportIndex()]]
    );
  }

  function Contest(participants, sports) {
    this.participants = participants;
    this.sports = sports;
  }

  Contest.prototype.assignParicipants = assignParicipants;

  const contest = constructFrom(Contest, participants, sports);

  return contest.assignParicipants();
}
console.log(func(participants, sports));
```