# c# Помогите правильно реализовать многопоточность

Tags: c#

В программу загружаются ссылки из txt и добавляются в очередь.
Далее нужно брать ссылку - переходить по ней и парсить значение online
И последнее это склеить ссылку и ответ парсера.
p/s : учу c# чуть больше недели, сильно не пиннайте )

Многопоточность я реализовал так:

```
for (int i = 1; i < load.Count; i++)
            {
                Thread myThread = new Thread(Proccess);
                myThread.IsBackground = true;
                myThread.Start();
```

код метода Process

```
public void Proccess()
        {
            string url;
            while (load.Count > 0)
            {
                lock (locks)
                {
                    var que = load.Dequeline();
                    url = que;
                }
                try
                {
                    hsettings.Reque(url);
                    Invoke((() =>
                    {

                        textBox1.AppendText(url + " | " + hsettings.online + '\r' + '\n');

                    }));
                }
```

В результате я получаю

https://Myurl1 | 1000 online
https://Myurl2 | 1200 online
https://Myurl3 | 1000 online

Хотя в Myurl 3 online = 1500, но почему то был взят результат из Myurl1
И каждый запуск выводит разные данные. Я так понимаю, что из за неправильно реализации многопоточности.

Для более точной информации:

Метод Reque:

```
public void Reque(string line) \\ line берём из очереди
            {
                using (HttpRequest httpRequest = new()
                {
                    UserAgent = Http.RandomUserAgent(),
            AllowAutoRedirect = false,
         IgnoreProtocolErrors = true,
                   UseCookies = false,
        EnableEncodingContent = false,
                })
                

                    try
                    {

                  var status = httpRequest.Get($"{line}");
```

Мне нужно что-бы 10, 100 , 1000 url - без разницы сколько их будет, был получен ответ и из ответа надо достать информацию о кол-ве онлайн пользователей и склеить ссылку с этим кол-вом.
Но у меня получается каша.
lock пробовал, тоже самое.

Вопрос собственно вот в чём, как из потока сохранить полученную информацию ?

В List ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752593/179763 ?

Comment: Там реализовано через async\await
Хотелось бы понять как сделать тоже самое через thread

Comment: У вас объект `hsettings` один на все потоки получается, и все потоки меняют его состояние? Ну вот и получается, что вы печатаете из него значение в одном потоке, а в это время другой поток уже поменял его значение. Лучше использовать в разных потоках разные, не пересекающиеся объекты. А где используете одинаковые, там либо объекты должны быть специально для такого использования предназначены, либо надо делать `lock`, но слишком большой кусок кода под `lock` сведёт на нет всю пользу от многопоточности.

Comment: _Хотелось бы понять как сделать тоже самое через thread_ - зачем? И что такое `Invoke`? Winforms? Process - стандартный класс в .NET, вы бы переименовали, чтобы не путать людей. Что такое `hsettings`? Что такое `load`? По этому обрубку кода ничего не понятно. Покажите все недостающие части.

Comment: Вот тут ваша проблема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433887

Comment: Да, там другой язык, но та же самая ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше использовать Parallel (кто-то может раскритиковать это, ибо принято использовать Task для web части)

```
private readonly ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2 };
private int[] result;
public void Main()
{
    string path = @"C:\links.txt";
    string[] urls = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    result = new int[urls.Length];
    Parallel.For(0, urls.Length, parallelOptions, i => ParseUrl(i, urls[i]));
    for(int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine($"{urls[i]}: {result[i]}");
}
private void ParseUrl(int index, string url)
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   int value = int.Parse(/*Какие-то действия, например можно скачать саму страницу и найти в ней значение.*/);
   result[i] = value;
}
```

Comment: Цитата: _Хотелось бы понять как сделать тоже самое через thread_

Comment: `new WebClient()` устарел, умер, закопан и разложился, и зачем он тут?

Comment: @aepot, изменил на HttpClient, как вы предлагаете реализовать нормальную систему через Thread? Делать свой замороченный ThreadPool?

Comment: Это лучше у автора спросить, как я понял, его не особо заботит время на спавн потоков.

Answer (score 0):

Узким местом был парсер кол-ва онлайн пользователей, а так-же запись этих данных в textbox.

Решение: обернуть в mutex:

```
var status = httpRequest.Get($"{url}");

                    mutexObj.WaitOne();

                    Respon = status.ToString();

                    GetUrl = Parse(Respon, "(?<=online_users_id\">).*?(?=</div>)");

textBox1.BeginInvoke(() => { textBox1.AppendText($" {url} | {GetUrl}" + '\r' + '\n'); });

mutexObj.ReleaseMutex();
```